# What is the correct representation of the generalized gamma function?

Tags: special-functions, gamma-function, symmetric-matrices, convex-cone

The *NIST Digital Library of Mathematical Functions* defines the multivariate gamma function as
$$
\Gamma_{m}\left(s_{1},\dots,s_{m}\right)=\int_{\boldsymbol{\Omega}}\mathrm{etr%
}\left(-\mathbf{X}\right)\left|\mathbf{X}\right|^{s_{m}-\frac{1}{2}(m+1)}\prod%
_{j=1}^{m-1}|(\mathbf{X})_{j}|^{s_{j}-s_{j+1}}\mathrm{d}{\mathbf{X}},
$$
see [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/35.3#E2) for all the definitions of the variables. Another representation is given by
$$
\Gamma_{m}\left(s_{1},\dots,s_{m}\right)=\pi^{m(m-1)/4}\prod_{j=1}^{m}\Gamma%
\left(s_{j}-\tfrac{1}{2}(j-1)\right),
$$
see [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/35.3#E5).

The book *Analysis on Symmetric Cones* by Faraut and Korányi (1994) has in my eyes the **same definition**, but in their Theorem VII.1.1. the representation suddenly has a 2 in it, which I marked in red below.
[image]
Note that to translate to the representation of
*NIST Digital Library of Mathematical Functions*  we have $n=m(m+1)/2$, $r=m$, $d=1$. Also, see below for the definitions of all variables according to Faraut and Korányi.

### **Where does the 2 in Faraut and Korányi come from?**

[image]

Comment: I implemented this function in my R package **HypergeoMat**, and I intensively tested it. There's no $2$ in my code.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Thank you for your comment. I wrote to Prof. Jacques Faraut and he kindly answered the following: The appearance of a power of $2$ comes from the following fact. All along the book Analysis on symmetric cones, we have used
the Euclidean measure on a Euclidean space $V$. It is the Lebesgue
measure normalized by the condition that the volume of a hypercube 
whose sides have length one is equal to one. If $x_j$ are the coordinates
of $x$ in $V$ with respect to an orthonormal basis, then the Euclidean measure
is the product of the Lebesgue measures $dx_j$...

Comment: ... This is natural in case there is no canonical basis.
In case of a simple Euclidean Jordan algebra we consider the inner product
$(x,y)=trace(xy)$. 
Then in case of $V=Sym(n,R)$,
$(x,x)=\sum _i (x_{ii})^2+2\sum _{i<j} (x_{ij})^2$.
It follows that the Euclidean measure is given by
$\prod dx_{ii} \times 2^{(n-r)/2}\prod _{I<j} x_{ij}$.